# iOS 11 - map cluster annotation icon size behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, ios11

Is there any way to resize the large annotation as same as the left ones.It is **iOS11** behaviour and I want the unique size for all annotations like before.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done for my project

In delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
```

1) create the annotation view

```
MKAnnotationView *annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:currentAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"Cluster"];
```

2) set the frame and other properties

```
[annView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,100,100)]; //(Important)
annView.canShowCallout = YES;
[annView setCenterOffset:CGPointMake(0, -18)];
```

3) add image view as sub view with same frame size

```
UIImageView *homeImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage cachedImage:@"GroupPin"]];
[homeImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,100,100)]; //(Important)
[annView addSubview:homeImage];
return annView;
```

and you are done.